# is the amortized cost for increment and decrement binary counter the same?

Tags: amortized-analysis

is the amortized cost for increment and decrement binary counter the same?
i.e O(n) for n increments or decrements?
Also can somebody explain how to calculate the amortised cost of a binary decrement counter using the potential method.

Comment: Do you mean n consecutive increments or consecutive decrements, or an arbitrary mixture of n operations?

Comment: just for n decrements

Comment: as in just increments compared with decrements

Comment: This is not a programming problem. Try http://cs.stackexchange.com